# Displaying a single record from Database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two methods in my `callsController`. The first is called `newCall` and it displays all the records from a DB table, it looks like this :

```
public function newCall(){

   $new_calls = new_calls::all();     //fetches everything in the new_calls table in the database
    return view('calls.newCall')->with('new_calls', $new_calls);     //passes it to the view
}
```

This function is working well and all the records are successfully retrieved in my view.

The issue is with the second method `viewCall` whose aim is to show data for a single `call` when its name is clicked from the list of `newCalls`.

Currently, I have just this:

```
public function viewCall(){
    return view('calls.viewCall');
}
```

I plan on formatting the data from the database (for a particular call) with some static text while displaying it in my `viewCall.blade.php`.

I wasn't really sure what to put in web.php, so my routes look like this :

```
Route::get('/calls/newCall', 'CallsController@newCall');
Route::get('/calls/viewCall/{id}', 'CallsController@viewCall')->name('viewCall');
```

Can someone help me make this work? I just want to see the associative array with the record from the database when I click on a call's name. What do I need to add in routes and in my view?

This is my `newCall.blade.php`

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table no-margin table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Terminal ID</th>
            <th>Terminal Name</th>
            {{-- <th>Fault Description</th> --}}
            <th>Call Logged On</th>
            <th>ATM Variant</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @if(count($new_calls) > 0)
        @foreach($new_calls as $calls)
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/calls/viewCall/{{$calls->id}}" title="view more details">{{$calls->terminal_id}}</a></td>
            <td>{{$calls->terminal_name}}</td>
            {{-- <td style="width:350px">{{$calls->fault_description}}</td> --}}
            <td>{{$calls->created_at}}</td>
            <td>{{$calls->atm_variant}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        @else
        <h1>No new Calls</h1>
        @endif
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is my `viewCall.blade.php`

```
<address>
    <strong>{{$new_call->client_name}}</strong><br>
    {{$new_call->address}}<br>
    <b>Phone: {{$new_call->phone}}</b> <br>
    <b>Email: {{$new_call->email}}</b>
</address>
```

nb: I have also tried using `{{$calls->email}}` but it's returning undefined variable: calls and new_calls in each case

Comment: Check my answer below and tell me if it works for you or not.

Comment: Add your `newcall.blade.php` and `viewcall.blade.php` file and I will look at it.

Comment: Did you updated your viewCall function as shown in my answer below?

Comment: yes...please view the updated version of my post..I included my foreach statement.. am still getting the `undefined variable calls` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is get the `new_calls` model by the `ID`. Which you can do like so:

routes/web.php

`Route::get('/calls/viewCall/{id}', 'CallsController@viewCall');`

CallsController.php

```
public function viewCall($id) // the id in the url
{
    $new_call = new_calls::find($id);

    return view('calls.viewCall')->with('new_call', $new_call);
}
```

In your view (I assume you're looping through all the calls to display them) create a link.

```
// your existing foreach
@foreach($x as $y)
    <a href="/calls/viewCall/{{$y->id}}">View Call</a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: That's what `return view('calls.viewCall')->with('new_call', $new_call);` does. In your view, you can access the call like so: `$new_call` with any properties.

Comment: Just add the view that you want the link to the call page in and I'll look at it.

Comment: I tried `<small class="pull-right">Call logged on: {{$new_call->created_at}} </small>`  and I got the undefined variable `new_call` error

Comment: You should use `{{$new_call->created_at}}`. Because the properties get passed into the view as `$new_call`

Comment: Please add all relevant views to your post: `viewcall.blade.php` and the one that you have all the calls in.

Comment: The other view I need to fix it is `newcall.blade.php`

Comment: I just added the views..kindly check the post

Comment: thanks...I made some errors in my variable names and I have corrected them..my code now workes....thanks soo much... i really appreciate

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
public function viewCall($id)
{
    return view('calls.viewCall', ['call' => new_calls::findOrFail($id)]);
}
```

This will get the `id` from the route and call a function to find the object with the given `id`.

If you have problems to deal with the variable in the view. Try to check the object using `dd`. Try this:

```
public function viewCall($id)
{
    $new_call = new_calls::find($id);
    dd($new_call);
}
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#basic-controllers

Comment: nothing is there except HTML and CSS codes but they are all imported as the headers and the footer

Comment: I was hoping to view the data in its raw state ie in array so i can customize the view

Comment: The variable that is going to be sent to `viewCall` is `$call`. In the view you can get attributes from this variable. I edited my answer with a debug code. Try to check if $new_call is printed correctly.

Comment: it returned the following new_calls {#234 ▼
  #fillable: array:6 [▶]
  #table: "new_calls"
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:10 [▶]
  #original: array:10 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
 ...and others
}   but i want it to return the information of the call I clicked in an array

Comment: thanks...I made some errors in my variable names and I have corrected them..my code now workes....thanks soo much... i really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I recommend too looking at naming convetions and route model binding and type hinting in the controller.
Then you'd have something like this:

```
    public function viewCall(NewCall $newcall)
{
    return view('calls.viewCall')->with($newcall);
}
```

and route would be like this:

```
Route::get('/calls/viewCall/{newcall}', 'CallsController@viewCall')->name('viewCall');
```

Comment: thanks for your response but it says "Class App\Http\Controllers\NewCall does not exist"

Comment: So where you did: $new_call = new_calls::find($id);    new_calls is your class.  That is poor naming convention.  Your model is new_calls and should be singular.  Think of a model as 1 row in the DB.  new_call::allI() = all rows.  new_fall::find($id) == 1 row.  I would change my model to NewCall but since you did it like that already you can do:   Public function viewCall(new_calls, $newcall) { return view('calls.viewCall')->with($newcall);  } .    Now what you are type hinting at is $newcall is an instance of new_call.  It is an eloquent.

Comment: thanks...I made some errors in my variable names and I have corrected them..my code now workes....thanks soo much... i really appreciate

Comment: @Austin .  Really read those laravel docs.  Route model binding and type hinting are so important and help keep code clean/readable, which will go a long way.  Good luck with your project.